# select distinct records with exclusion after table join

Tags: python, sql

I have 2 tables and I join them.

The resulting table contains duplicate `id`s.

How do I just keep the last record for those duplicate records?

Furthermore, table3 contains a set of `id`s that should be removed from the resultant table obtained previously.

What should the command be?

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1)
cmd1 = "(select id, filename from table1 where group = 1) m"
cmd2 = "(select id, type, date from table2 where is_good = 1 and date > '" + start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') +"') n "

cmd = "select m.id, m.filename, n.type, n.date, from " + \
          cmd1 + " join " + cmd2 + " on " + "m.id = n.id"
```

Comment: what is your db ? please show tables schema,  some input data and what you expect as an output.

Comment: are you sure id is a key in both the cmd1/2 tables? Are there no duplicate ids in either? I'd bet there are.